# JDA message.getReactions.size always returns 0

Tags: java, bots, discord-jda

```
Emote Giveaway = Rmessage.getGuild().getEmoteById("794316713524461609");
            Rmessage.addReaction(Giveaway).queue();   
            System.out.println(Rmessage.getReactions().size());
```

This code is part of a giveaway Command and I need the people that reacted to the emoji. But it cant get the people that reacted to the emote because It doesnt register the emote. Y tho?

Comment: because queue is async and the message object isn't getting updated. use events.

Comment: Well how can I do that?